# Android canvas drawCircle coordinates origin point

Tags: android, android-canvas, graphics2d

I want to draw dynamically a circle on top of a drawable. So i created this class:

```
public class CustomTextViewDrawable extends LayerDrawable {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private View mParent;

    public CustomTextViewDrawable(View parent, Drawable[] layers) {
        super(layers);
        mParent = parent;

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        float radius = 5;

        // Top-left corner
        float centerX = 0;
        float centerY = 0;

        // Draw circle
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And my usage is the following:

```
// Get the drawable set in XML file ...
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[] { imageView.getDrawable() };
Drawable d = new CustomTextViewDrawable(imageView, layers);
// ... and replace it
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

What i wanted to get is 1/4 of a circle with center in top-left corner, but what i get is the following (with "show layout bounds" options enabled in my device):

[image: screenshot]

Can someone tell me why the point (0, 0) is there? Shouldn't it be placed on top-left corner?

### Edit

Here is the XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >


        <!-- Some views here ... -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/questions_answers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_help"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/..."
            android:contentDescription="@string/..." />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Some other views here ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could be padding, check your xml

Comment: @OneWay no, I set padding to RelativeLayout, not to the ImageView. I attached the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw that point in your ImageView or set to your imageView android:scaleType="fitStart". Maybe your imageView creates some padding by default which depends on scaleType.

Comment: I tried setting fitStart scaleType, but the result is the same. I ended up retrieving from "canvas.getClipBounds()"